# possible bug in opencv 3.2 cv::compare

Tags: c++, opencv

I call cv::compare with cv::compare(_src1, _src2, _dst, op)

_src1 is an matrix with size rows = 4, cols = 1, type = 6

_src2 is an matrix with size rows = 1, cols = 1, type = 6

_dst is an empty matrix

op = cv::CMP_LT

The function goes into a infinite loop and then crashes with stack overflow.
I find that in the function cv::compare, it calls a function cv::checkScalar and if it returns true, cv::compare is called again.

The code in cv::checkscalar has a line that when sz == Size(1, 4), the function returns true. Hence when my input is with rows = 4, cols = 1, the function cv::compare enters infinite loop.

I am not sure whether it is a bug or my implementation is not correct.

## Code

```
cv::Mat mat1 = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 1, CV_32F);
mat1.convertTo(mat1, CV_64F);
cv::Mat mat2 = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 1, CV_32F);
mat2.convertTo(mat2, CV_64F);
cv::Mat outmat;
cv::compare(mat1, mat2, outmat, cv::CMP_LT);
```

Comment: If you posted the faulty code, it'd be much easier to help you.

Comment: I have posted the faulty code. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: My original code is industrial code so i cannot post it here. But I can repeat the same problem with the above code. I have tried replacing the mat2 by a single scalar zero and it went well.  I suspect there is a bug with  the mentioned combination of input. I am curious what the (1,4) means in the cv::checkscalar function

Comment: Just a not, you should use cv::CMP_LT instead of 3, makes your code more readable, even by you in a couple months...

Comment: It sure does look like a bug.

Comment: do you know what (1,4) means in the cv::checkscalar function?

Comment: It's the size of the matrix.  Can't figure out why (1, 4)  would be special case for CV_64F.  You should contact the opencv team.